# MVC Controllers parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there any order or pattern that action parameters in an MVC controller follow.
For example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddFiles(HttpPostedFileBase file, int catid, string description)
```

How does the controller know that this certain post parameter is for catid and so on.

Comment: When you call *"ASP.NET MVC"* framework just *"the MVC"*, it is like referring to IE as *"the internet"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default model binder when trying to bind the `catid` parameter looks for a value with that name. It looks in the form values, route data, query string and http file collection. Take a look at [this](http://www.howmvcworks.net/OnModelsAndViewModels/TheBeautyThatIsTheModelBinder).